# Can`t Create Admin System User on Facebook Business

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-business-manager

I created an app on Facebook business manager, and want to generate a permanent token to use the whatsapp message API. I was able to create a system user with employee access but not admin.

When I try and create a system user with admin role I get this:

[[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl2P6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl2P6.png)]

Error received when trying to create

Everything I can find online makes it sound like I should just be able to make a system user. The business has already been verified.

I have read through the resources and can`t find a solutions.

Comment: 4 months later and the issue is still not fixed. I get the same error. Were you able to by-pass it somehow?

Comment: Sorry only saw your comment now. I ended up Completed all possible extra information and validations for the company, and the after 10 days the option suddenly became visible.

I was never able to move a user to system user, but could suddenly create a system user, Very tedious.